# Maven cannot resolve dependency because parent jar not found

Tags: maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

I am starting a Maven project with inherited poms.

The parent pom of the project is like:

```
<artifactId>service-parent</artifactId>
<groupId>group.parent</groupId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>child-of-parent</module> ...
</modules>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

So in the child module, if I understand well, the dependencies in  part will be inherited automatically, and those in the  part will have to be declared in child's pom. And I write this in child's pom:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>service-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>group.parent</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>service-child</artifactId>
<groupId>group.child</groupId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>child-of-child</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This child module has its own children modules. The third-level pom is thus as blow:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>service-child</artifactId>
    <groupId>group.child</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>service-child-child</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>service-child</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It's a little wired like this as in the beginning of pom it already has  tag which is the same thing as its dependency. That is because if I copy the dependencies in its parent there is a duplicate warning. 
And when I run `maven clean install`, it says

> Failed to execute goal on project service-child: Could not resolve dependencies for project service-parent:service-child:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   The following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   group.child:service-child:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT,
>   group.parent:service-parent:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact
>   group.child:service-child:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

I know that it's an aggregation way instead of inheritance but I prefer this way in the future I would like to test and run module by module (I tried btw the inheritance way by removing the modules declaration in parent poms and it did work). Do you have any idea why this happen?

Comment: Please make a github project of it and so one can take a look ...

Answer (score 1):

That's because the type (packaging) of `service-child` is `pom` and not `jar`.

It is not possible to have a project with `jar` packaging with submodules.

If you still need to declare that dependency, use the following declaration - note `type` element with `pom` value:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>service-child</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

That declaration does not bring any new dependencies since `service-child-child` inherits all dependencies from it's parent `service-child` already.

Check out [Introduction to the POM - Project Inheritance](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance) for more information on inheritance and aggregation in Maven.

Comment: `jar` would not work with the aggregation structure. I tried though and got this message `The project group.parent:service-parent:1.0-SNAPSHOT has 1 error
[ERROR]     'packaging' with value 'jar' is invalid. Aggregator projects require 'pom' as packaging.`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. As I said in my answer "It is not possible to have a project with jar packaging with submodules." You should keep modules with `jar` packaging separate from modules with `pom` packaging.